# Only getting list of files on /var/www/html folder

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, xampp

I'm trying to host my laravel app on an ubuntu machine
I added the laravel app to the /var/www/html folder which is root directory for my domain on apache conf file. But when I access my domain, I only get the list of files in /var/www/html folder. When I insert a index.html file for test, it works perfectly when I access the domain. What can be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is served out of `index.php` inside the `public` folder.

You are getting your list of files because your domain is pointing to `var/www/html` which contains the root of your Laravel application and not the `public` directory which contains `index.php`.

If you go to `www.yourdomain.com/public` you will find your application served correctly if your apache is set up to recognize `index.php` which it should be.

To fix this up so you don't need to use public inside the URL you can just edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to point your directory to `/var/www/html/public` and then you will be able to access it through `www.yourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 3):

Your apache needs to be configured to recognize index.php as well as index.html.  This is done by setting the directoryindex in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: where is this file? I just edited the file conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: Depends on your system, most often its at /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf or /etc/apache2/httpd.conf